# angular 4 - select option change

Tags: angular4-forms

I need a select option in angular 4, but data binding doesn´t work.

I have a function "ChangeTable" in (ngModelchange) but the parameter always that i send in the function is "undefined".

I have tried to went $event.target.value but it also go "undefined"

this is my code html

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="selectTable"  (ngModelChange)="ChangeTable($event)" >
    <option>Select item</option> 
    <option *ngFor="let table of tables" [value]="table.id">
        {{table.Description}}
    </option>
</select>
```

this is my code in component

`ChangeTable(ev:any){ 
var tabla=this.selectTabla;
}`

You can help me, please.thanks

Comment: `'targer' !== 'target'`...

Answer (score 0):

**ngModelChange** itself extracts the value from $event so you no more need to do `$event.target.value`. In your case there must be no id exist in table object that's may be the reason you are getting `undefined` whenever your binding value property with table's id(`[value]=table.id`).

Check your table's data once and you can also refer this [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-3fm2ff) where I've demonstrated your use-case.

Comment: Hello Rajat, I tried it and work ... but when I use a model it is not work